# How to update a column without loading the object in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
Foo.where(:some_id => 1).update_all(:some_columnn => "1")
```

Is this the right way to update Foo? I don't want to do a find and update the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is the right way, but remember, **no callbacks or validations will be executed**.

BTW, update_all accepts conditions also. Like this

```
Foo.update_all({:some_columnn => "1"}, {:some_id => 1})
```

Answer (score 4):

[As of Rails 4](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all), the conditions are no longer supplied on the `update_all` method, but are instead specified on the preceding collection. For example,

```
# updates everything, as usual
Foo.update_all(some_column: '1')

# update only the specified rows
Foo.where(some_id: 1).update_all(some_column: '1')
```

Answer (score 2):

It is the right approach if you don't want to instantiate an object, but keep in mind that this also means it won't perform any of your models validations or callbacks - it goes straight to a SQL update command.

[Further information](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all)

Answer (score 1):

You can use *conditions*,according to the api of [update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class)

update_all(updates, conditions = nil, options = {})

So you can do:

```
Foo.update_all(:some_column => '1', :some_id => 1)
```